# Intel GMA X3100 Driver

Tags: graphic-drivers, macbook, intel

Anyone tell if there's driver for Intel GMA X3100?
I installed Elementary OS on an old Mac but it uses an alternative driver and works badly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "alternative driver" for Intel GPUs. Intel releases their Linux GPU drivers as [Free Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_graphics_device_driver#Intel) and those are installed by default on your system. Your hardware might be simply too outdated to run properly with elementary OS, but "works badly" is unfortunately not really informative concerning the problems you experience.

Comment: Being more specific, after installing Elementary OS, the video is identified as Intel GMA 950. The resolution is correct, but any movement of the mouse for example, occurs flashes on the screen.

Comment: Some animations in elementary OS are flickering on my Sony VAIO VGN-NR120E which has this GPU although it runs Windows 10 very smoothly (and plays games such as solitaire and mines smoothly)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a later kernel with `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-wily`

Note that this might break certain peripherals such as WiFi or sound, but booting back into the older kernel and uninstalling should fix any problems. Just make sure you can see grub before trying this.